# Javascript error - AddEventListener

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I am following a Traversy Media web tutorial on youtube [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ophW7Ask_0) in which he creates a modal from scratch, and at minute `17.00` I get an error -

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"
```

> Code Snippet

```js
//Get modal element
var modal = document.getElementById('simpleModal');
//Get open modal button
var modalBtn = document.getElementById('modalBtn');
//Get close button
var closeBtn = document.getElementById('closeBtn');


//Listen for click
modalBtn.addEventListener('click', openModal);

//Fucntion to open modal
function openModal() {
  console.log(123);
}
```

```html
<body>

  <button #id="modalBtn" class="button">Click Here</button>

  <div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
      <p>Hello...I am a modal</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: I don't think this question is duplicated as OP did not added the id attribute properly in the HTML and got that error.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you do not have a button (or any element) with id `modalBtn` in your HTML page due to `#id` added in place of `id`. Thus, changing `#id` in `<button #id="modalBtn" class="button">Click Here</button>` will fix your error. Javascript will throw an error if it did not find that element in which you are adding a event listener. And `#id` in attribute do not mean `id` attribute.

```js
//Get modal element
var modal = document.getElementById('simpleModal');
//Get open modal button
var modalBtn = document.getElementById('modalBtn');
//Get close button
var closeBtn = document.getElementById('closeBtn');


//Listen for click
modalBtn.addEventListener('click', openModal);

//Fucntion to open modal
function openModal(){
console.log(123);
}
```

```html
<button id="modalBtn" class="button">Click Here</button>

<div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
        <p>Hello...I am a modal</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button #id="modalBtn" class="button">Click Here</button>
```

Remove character # in the above line and try.

**Edit:**
It should look something like this

```
<button id="modalBtn" class="button">Click Here</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my issue :)

Comment: You're welcome :) Happy coding